# Unable to get git branch from puppet agent

Tags: git, github, puppet, git-branch, puppet-enterprise

I've the following command to execute puppet agent in a server. Its puppet master contains a puppetfile which contains several modules stored in different git repositories.

Well, I need to execute puppet agent pointing to the correct git branch to get the modules.

This environment is PROD an it is properly configured as there are a lot of people working on it but I'm new using it and I need help!

I've executed the following command but it doesn't work:

`sudo puppet agent -t --environment my_branch`

And I get:

`Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Find my_branch/node/hostname_agent_server?transaction_uuid=fb7c33d0-dab2-4c36-be0a-94870f6fbfcc&fail_on_404=true resulted in 404 with the message: Not Found: Could not find environment 'develop'`

My branch is "develop/xxxx/xxxx" for this reason the code above mentions "Could not find environment 'develop'

Could you please help me with the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is getting confused because of the slashes in your branch name.  Here is an excerpt from the Puppet docs:

> [Allowed Environment Names](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/environments_creating.html#allowed-environment-names)
>
> Environment names can contain lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores. That is, they must match the following regular expression:
>
> `\A[a-z0-9_]+\Z`

Comment: I got it. The '/' must be replaced by '_' due to a hook which is working performs the conversion. Thanks!